# databind to radio button (group)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to somehow bind an entity field(?) to a radio button.

Perhaps an example:

I have a groupbox with two radio buttons in it: Toss Won and Toss Lost.
I have a database field called TossWon. What I want to happen, is when Toss Won is Checked, then TossWon should be 1 (i.e. true). When Toss Lost is Checked, TossWon should be false.

How can I do this? Should I be binding to some property of the groupbox (don't think so), or to one or both of the radio buttons?

I know I can use events, but I'm wondering if there is a 'better' way.

Comment: What techniques have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution avoiding events is to add calculated field `TossLost= NOT(TossWon)` in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Data bind `TossWon` to both radio buttons.

Then handling the [Binding.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) / [Binding.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the radio buttons

```
// Displaying data, true if data is 1 else false
rdoTossWin.DataBindings[0].Parse += (sender, e) => e.Value = ((int)e.Value) == 1;
// Change the true to 1 and false to 0
rdoTossWin.DataBindings[0].Format += (sender, e) => e.Value = (bool)e.Value ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As HubertL pointed out, only one filed suffices. 
You should put both radio buttons in a groupbox so that checking one causes the other one be unchecked without writing any code. The you can simply bind property `TossWon` to `Checked` property of `rdTossWin`:

```
rdTossWin.DataBindings.Add("Checked", yourDataSource,"TossWin");
```